# How to constrain users to sort only a given element in a list?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 and the jquery-rails v2.0.2 gems (including jQuery UI). In a my view I have implemented a "basic" / "simple" [jQuery UI Sortable Interaction](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) and I would like to constrain users to *sort only a given element in the list*. That is, for example, if I have the following sortable list:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item ...

I would make only the `Item 3` to be sortable and the others to be not. Is it possible?

Comment: This should be done as the jqueryui sortable page says "To only prevent sorting on certain items, pass a jQuery selector into the cancel option. Cancelled items remain valid sort targets for others."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`handle` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-handle).  With HTML like:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li><span id="thisone">Item 3</span></li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

You can set the sortable properties thus:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({handle: '#thisone'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about the result. But as per my idea below process should work.
You can try replacing in your javascript

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
```

with

```
$( "#sortable .innerElement" ).sortable();
```

Considering, "innerElement" is the class of the required DOM Element to be sorted.
With this approach, you should be able to make multiple selected elements to be sortable, by applying "innerElement" class.

Hope it works for you :)